# What is the best mobile "text-to-speech" and "speech-to-text" tool for both android and IOS?

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

Would you please help me to find out the best mobile "text-to-speech" and "speech-to-text" tool for both android and IOS?

I searched the web and found some tools such as:

For Speech to Text(STT):

```
1.react-native-voice

2.RNSpeakChat

3.Using Google Cloud

4.SpeechRecognizer

5.react-native-watson 

6.react-speech-recognition

7.react-native-speech-recognition
```

and for text to speech (TTS):

```
1.react-native-tts

2.react-native-watson

3.react-native-speech
```

But I couldn't find which one is the best choice. Would you please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Speech to text you can refer this article as it explains precisely and also it uses `react-native-voice` as its an easy library to get started with . [react-native-speech-to-text](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-react-native-speech-recognition-d9ae54960565)

For text-to-speech functionality, as per documentation of [react-native-tts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tts) looks simple. you could implement that.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Would you please let me know which packages you yourself used before and why?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions for speech recognition in 2023 is [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) from OpenAI

[Whisper CPP is](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp) a high performance port of original Whisper

There is a binding for React Native:

https://github.com/mybigday/whisper.rn